# What famous formal literature or writing has used "still more" as a conjunction?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my English Language Learners Stack Exchange post: [What famous formal literature or writing has used "still more" as a conjunction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332579/what-famous-formal-literature-or-writing-has-used-still-more-as-a-conjunction)

#### How can we improve or salvage [What famous formal literature or writing has used "still more" as a conjunction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/332579) please ?

Kate Bunting and I spent lots of time researching this question, which definitely can benefit others in the future!

---

Don't (ask me to) reword or paraphrase these sentences! I need this syntax.

Please  list some example sentences from the English literary canon that write [***still <sup>more</sup>***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332045/how-do-i-deduce-when-to-use-still-less-vs-still-more-as-conjunctions) in this context, as a conjunction?

My number 1 life goal is H (Happiness). My number 2 life goal is  L (Longevity). I shall communicate that I like H more than L.

> I like L, ***still <sup>more</sup>*** H.

W (War) irks me more, and is deadlier, than R (Racism). I shall communicate that I hate W more than R.

> I hate R, ***still <sup>more</sup>***  W.

Answer (score 2):

Research or no, this question is off topic because it's neither a question nor directly about learning English.

First, it is a request for data, and ***[not a question at all](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)***. Questions on this network ***must be questions***. We do not accept requests for people to do any work other than answer questions. Regardless of your intent in making this request, it's not a question, so it's off topic.

Second, this request is **not inherently about learning English**. Regardless of your intent in making this request, there is no direct connection between the content of this request and learning English. Based only on the content, it would make just as much sense on EL&U.SE, Literature.SE, Writing.SE, Law.SE, or even Biblical Hermeneutics.SE. If you want to know the syntactic rules for using "still more" correctly, then ask that. If you want to know whether a particular instance of it is correct, then ask that. Those are directly related to learning English. This request, on its face, is not.

So, if you have a ***question*** that you're trying to answer with this data, and the question is ***about learning English***, please ask it directly.

Beyond that, your claim that it "*definitely can benefit others in the future*" is unsupportable. I'm confident that nobody will ever come to this site again looking for a list of contexts where someone used "still more" in this sense.

Answer (score -2):

This was closed as lacking research. But the comments make it clear that a fair amount of research was in fact done. I have therefor reopened the question. Mind you, the usage is no longer common, still less would I recommend it to any learner. But it is now available for answers to be posted.